# How does an old 32bit linux program end up calling a 64bit library?

Tags: c++, linux, x86, shared-libraries, 64-bit

I have an old 32bit C++ app I need to run under RedHatEL7. RHEL7 has both 32 and 64 bit versions of libthread_db.so.1 installed. But then somehow the app ends up loading /lib64/libthread_db.so.1. How can I stop this happening? A console log shows this:

```
mybox:/home/worknet$ which corbanames
~/bin/corbanames
mybox:/home/worknet$ file ~/bin/corbanames
/home/worknet/bin/corbanames: **ELF 32-bit** LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not stripped
mybox:/home/worknet$ locate libthread_db.so.1
**/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1**
/usr/lib/i686/nosegneg/libthread_db.so.1
**/usr/lib64/libthread_db.so.1**
mybox:/home/myuser$ gdb corbanames
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-100.el7_4.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/myuser/bin/corbanames...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/myuser/bin/corbanames 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "**/lib64/libthread_db.so.1**".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080544a1 in getStackFrame<5> (this=<optimized out>) at StackCache.hpp:89
89  StackCache.hpp: No such file or directory.
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-196.el7_4.2.i686 libgcc-4.8.5-16.el7_4.2.i686 libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.2.i686
(gdb) bt
#0  0x080544a1 in getStackFrame<5> (this=<optimized out>) at StackCache.hpp:89
#1  fetchFrameData<5> (this=<optimized out>) at StackCache.hpp:76
#2  ECONZ::Leak::Impl::StackCache::StackCache (this=0xffffd01c)
    at StackCache.cpp:66
#3  0x08050c00 in ECONZ::Leak::Impl::HeaderList::doNew (size=32, 
    throwFlag=false) at leakTracker.cpp:138
#4  0x08050d83 in operator new (size=32) at leakTracker.cpp:284
#5  0xf79762ac in ACE_OS_Object_Manager::instance ()
    at Object_Manager_Base.cpp:185
#6  0xf7976357 in ACE_OS_Object_Manager_Manager::ACE_OS_Object_Manager_Manager
    (this=0xf7a2318c <ACE_OS_Object_Manager_Manager_instance>)
    at Object_Manager_Base.cpp:488
#7  0xf7976393 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, 
    __priority=65535) at Object_Manager_Base.cpp:504
#8  0xf79763cf in global constructors keyed to ACE_Object_Manager_Base::ACE_Object_Manager_Base() () at Object_Manager_Base.cpp:505
#9  0xf79c9816 in __do_global_ctors_aux ()
   from /usr/local/ACE_wrappers_32/lib/libACE.so.5.7.9
#10 0xf78ce475 in _init () from /usr/local/ACE_wrappers_32/lib/libACE.so.5.7.9
#11 0xf7fe9b5d in _dl_init_internal () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#12 0xf7fdb04f in _dl_start_user () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
(gdb)
```

Comment: RHEL7 is a commercial Linux distribution that comes with a support contract. Any particular reason you're asking this on stackoverflow.com, instead of filing a bugzilla ticket with redhat, using your support contract?

Comment: I think this line `Using host libthread_db library "**/lib64/libthread_db.so.1**".` only indicates `gdb` using 64bit version of libthread_db, not your program.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/libthread_005fdb_002eso_002e1-file.html: `libthread_db` is a thread *debugging* library, used by GDB, not by the program you're debugging.  Use `ldd` to see what libraries it uses.  (Or look at `/proc/PID/maps` to see all files it has mapped.)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There are three particular reasons I'm using Stack Overflow. A) 17 years ago I had problems with Red Hat being either technically inept or obtuse in understanding technical issues with C/C++ compiler/linker problems (cf https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28625). Things might have changed since then, but I have a long memory B) I'm an outside contractor who's been asked to drag this app into the modern world, and do not have direct access to the support contract. C) On top of that, I presumed that this would be a general linux issue, and I often get good help here.

Comment: @hgminh, +peter Aha. I wondered why libthread_db was being used. ldd wasn't showing it (I thought maybe 2nd/3rd level). That's also triggered a thought that it could be the way it gets stack frames - I know the __builtin_[frame|return]_address semantics changed (function call arg must be constant, not a variable).

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was mistaken, as @hgminh and @PeterCordes pointed out - the 64bit library was an artefact of debugging.
The actual SIGSEGV turned out to be calls to __builtin_[frame|return]_address not being binary compatible. They have been refactored.